# How can I integrate Mathjax on my Next.js app to render inline and display equations using Latex?

Tags: node.js, next.js, mathjax, next.js13

I want to integrate Mathjax on my nextjs app.
I am using nextjs 13 and use app dir for routing
I want to my code rendered in server, so that is no need to rerender when user open the page.
I try to read documentation but still lack info.

Iwant to get `Some inline equation $x^2-2x+5=0$ will render inline.` and `Some display equation using duble dollar $$x^2-2x+5=0$$ will render display.`

That is my code

```
import { mathjax } from 'mathjax-full/js/mathjax.js';
import { TeX } from 'mathjax-full/js/input/tex.js';
import { SVG } from 'mathjax-full/js/output/svg.js';
import { liteAdaptor } from 'mathjax-full/js/adaptors/liteAdaptor.js';
import { RegisterHTMLHandler } from 'mathjax-full/js/handlers/html.js';

const inputTex = 'Persamaan $c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$';

const adaptor = liteAdaptor();
RegisterHTMLHandler(adaptor);

const tex = new TeX();
const svg = new SVG();
const html = mathjax.document('', { InputJax: tex, OutputJax: svg });

// Mode inline
const nodeInline = html.convert(inputTex, { display: false });
const svgCodeInline = adaptor.outerHTML(nodeInline);


// Mode display
const nodeDisplay = html.convert(inputTex, { display: true });
const svgCodeDisplay = adaptor.outerHTML(nodeDisplay);


export default function page() {
    return (
    <>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svgCodeInline }}></span>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svgCodeDisplay }}></span>
    </>
    )
}
```

But that will convert all text, not only formula between $. This is sample outpun
[Render all text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdXpv.png)
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to render only the equations between $$:

```js
export function RenderLatex(latex) {
  let result = latex.split("");
  let firstPos = null;
  let firstFounded = false;
  let returnString = latex;
  for (let i = 0; i < latex.length; i++) {
    if (latex[i] === "$" && !firstFounded) {
      firstFounded = true;
      firstPos = i;
    }
    if (firstFounded && i < 1 && firstPos === i - 1)
      firstFounded = false;
    else if (latex[i] === "$" && firstFounded && i !== firstPos) {
      firstFounded = false;
      result[firstPos] = ""
      result[i] = ""
      let firstPart = result.join("").slice(0, firstPos);
      let secondPart = result.join("").slice(i, result.join("").length);
      let addition = MathJax.tex2chtml((result.join("").substring(firstPos, i))).outerHTML;
      return RenderLatex(firstPart + addition + " " + secondPart)
    }
  }
  return returnString;
}
```